# "in feeding" instead of "food source"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> But like the male mosquito, females feed only on nectar for their food source.

If I rephrase  this sentence,

> female mosquitoes are compared to male mosquitoes in feeding.

But I have a doubt that I can use "in feeding" instead of "food source".

Comment: Why change a perfectly good sentence except for food source. Just food is fine. Nectar is their food, not their food source. Female mosquitoes feed on nectar in the same way as male mosquitoes.

Comment: @Lambie I just want to know whether I can use "in feeding" for "to eat".

Comment: with regard to feeding is in feeding, so yes. In feeding, mosquitoes and wasps are similar.

Comment: Do you mean to say that the food choices are comparable or that you compared them?

Comment: What @Willow Rex said. But since it seems they're actually ***the same*** (not just ***comparable, similar***) it would be more natural to actually *say* that. and idiomatically most people would probably use something like ***feeding habits*** rather than the bare gerund ***feeding***.

Answer (score -1):

You can always write :

- Male mosquitoes differ from female mosquitoes in their choice of food.
- The food source of male and female mosquitoes are compared.

Comment: do you mean **comparable** ?

Comment: **comparable** works. The user used **compared** in his statement, so did I.

Comment: It might be a regional thing, but to me they do not mean the same thing. I did ask the OP. In an experiment the two  could be compared.

Comment: The question is that I can use feeding in stead of food and the word "compared to" in stead of " similar to".

Comment: Then instead (one word) I'd use **similar** or the **same** as.